# Display uploaded image on page PHP

Tags: php, html

I am moving user's uploaded file to a directory which is working:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], "Uploaded_Fotos/" . $_FILES["foto"]["name"]);
```

I am having trouble displaying this photo in a table:

```
while($FormDataRow = mysql_fetch_array($formDataSQLObj))
{
    $Imagepath = "Uploaded_Fotos/";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
                echo "<img src='$Imagepath.$FormDataRow[16]'/>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
```

I have checked the src by echoing it and it seems to be correct: `Uploaded_Fotos/IMG_20130511_175116.jpg`

Only empty icon is displayed. Whats wrong?

Comment: check that the url of the src your echoing is valid

Comment: Maybe you should use absolute path starting with `/`?  `echo "<img src='/$Imagepath.$FormDataRow[16]'/>";`

Comment: and what happens when you go to that url in your browser?

Comment: When I try to display this image outside the table, it works.<img src="Uploaded_Fotos/IMG_20130511_175116.jpg" width="100px"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing img tag from echo statement:

```
echo "<td>";
?>
<img src="<?php echo $Imagepath.$FormDataRow[16]; ?>" width="100px"/>
<?php
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: IF you'll see in your previous code `<img src='$Imagepath.$FormDataRow[16]'/>` - the `img` path will be `Uploaded_Fotos/.IMG_20130511_175116.jpg`because no concatenation performed in this string.